# How can I build Qt for OS X 10.5 on 10.6

Tags: macos, qt, build

I'm trying to build a static, universal Qt from source on Mac OS X 10.6 using the following command:

```
sh configure -static -opensource -universal
```

The problem, I have been told, is that PPC is not supported on 10.6 so I am getting many errors and the build eventually fails.

So I need to build for a different target version of OS X - 10.4 or 10.5. How can I do that? Do I need to add some parameters to my configure line and, if so, which ones?

Comment: Before you even try to do static link, make sure it's allowed in the LGPL. You'll need to publish your source code if you statically link any LGPL code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277165/qt-single-exe-with-lgpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `-sdk` option to configure.  e.g.

`./configure -sdk /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -opensource -universal`

...if you want to make binaries targeting OSX 10.5 and later.

Statically linking is a separate issue again.  I would not recommend it, especially since OSX already supports app bundles anyway, which I believe gives most of the same benefits to the end-user as static linking.