# Qt missing library?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am trying to run my qt application on another (debian) machine. I get an error about missing libraries (for example, libQt5WebKitWidgets). Is it possible to bundle these libraries within my application ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either install the Qt libraries on the machine running your application, or statically link them into your application.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5692470/446554).

You could also try taking a look at the [Qt Installer Framework](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-Installer-Framework) as another alternative.