# Error in running Qt created executable on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

I have written a code that runs successfully on a ubuntu machine having Qt installed but when I'm trying to run the executable on another ubuntu machine that don't have Qt I am getting this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Widgets.so.5
```

Comment: a quick fix is: `sudo apt-get install libqt5gui5`. Depending on used features you need to install [other packages](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libqt5). Or install all by installing `libqt5-dev` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a shared build, you need the required shared Qt libraries on your system.

Alternatively if you want to build a standalone executable then you will have to compile it statically.

Following link maybe helpful:
[How to make binary distribution of Qt application for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934950/how-to-make-binary-distribution-of-qt-application-for-linux)

Comment: Putting shared library in the same folder containing binary works on Windows only , not Linux

Answer (score 0):

As is clear, the required Qt libraries are not installed on the other machine, you will need to install Qt libraries first.

The standard procedure followed on Linux, is to create a package (Debian, rpm, pacman etc.) Since you are using Ubuntu, you should create a Debian package with libqt5gui5 mentioned as dependency, so when you install the package, Qt libraries are automatically downloaded and installed if necessary.